# I want to improve something

Tags: adverb, modal-verb

Can I get a correction on my translation of the following sentences? I am a rock climber and a skier so I am trying to learn how to talk about my sporting activities with Germans I meet.

I want to improve my skiing.  ---> Ich wolle verbessern meine ski fahren.

I have improved my skiing now.  ----> Ich habe ski gefahren verbessern jetzt.

I must improve my skiing. --->  Ich musse verbessern mein ski fahren.

Comment: (not native speaker) mien, it sounds as spoken German :-) "mein" is the correct version. Germans have around 10 different dialects, but all of them is writing on the standard German (hochdeutsch). Your sentences sound me as if you had written what you hear.

Comment: You just did translate the words, not the sentence. German has a different word order than English (every language has its own grammar rules). You need to learn German grammar when you want to translate sentences.

Comment: @peterh: If he heard it like that, it can't be from native or fluent speakers. FWIW, German "mein" sounds like English "mine".

Comment: Sorry to say: But even Google Translate can do better than that (and it is known for its sometimes horrible translations)... I tried all of your sentences in google translate, and all translations are absolutely valid... As said in other comments: you need to learn German grammar. Just translating the words one by one does not give you even one valid sentence here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the conjugation of verbs and the right word order as well as when words start with upper and lower case.

> Ich möchte/will mein Skifahren verbessern.
>
> Ich habe mein Skifahren jetzt verbessert.
>
> Ich muss mein Skifahren verbessern.

Comment: So do adverbs come at the end of German sentences and the pronouns following the modal verb?  I am just trying to understand the rule.

Comment: In English you have the construction "[modal verb] to [verb in infinitive] [object]" but in German you have "[modal verb] [object] [verb in infinitive]" (with the pronoun before the object). The second sentence is perfect tense and that is why the verb is a participle II, but the pronoun+object is between modal verb and verb as well. The word at the end of the sentence is not an adverb because adverbs are words describing verbs (e.g. "_randomly_ improve").